# SearchBar in Material3 AndroidStudio didn't exist

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, android-jetpack-compose, searchbar

I'm new and beginner in Android Programming especially kotlin and jetpack compose, I'm following some tutorial about how to make a search bar but there is some main issue that I'm facing right now, that is the SearchBar function didn't exist nowadays even though the tutorial that I watched is 2 months ago. this is the code

```
package com.example.searchbarfinal

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.ColumnScope
import androidx.compose.material3.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterialScaffoldPaddingParameter")
@Composable
fun SearchBar(
    query: String,
    onQueryChange: (String) -> Unit,
    onSearch: (String) -> Unit,
    active: Boolean,
    onActiveChange: (Boolean) -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    enabled: Boolean = true,
    placeholder: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    leadingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    trailingIcon: @Composable (() -> Unit)? = null,
    shape: Shape = SearchBarDefaults.inputFieldShape,
    colors: SearchBarColors = SearchBarDefaults.colors(),
    tonalElevation: Dp = SearchBarDefaults.Elevation,
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = SearchBarDefaults.windowInsets,
    IOnteractionSource: MutableInteractionSource = remember {MutableInteractionSource()},
    content: @Composable ColumnScope.() -> Unit

){
    
}
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    Scaffold() {
        SearchBar(
            query = ,
            
        )
        
    }
}
```

Unresolved reference: SearchBarDefaults
Unresolved reference: SearchBarColors

and for the function of SearchBar I'm making manually instead calling automatically, can you guys please provide me some advice or help guys? Im using material 3 jetpack compose

thank you everyone

There is no SearchBar, SearchBarDefault, SearchBarColor in the material3 Jetpack Compose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Material 3 are you using? You need at least version [1.1.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3#1.1.0) as SearchBar was a new component then. Ideally, use this `implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.1`.

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your answer, and can i ask one question how to check the latest version for material3?

Comment: You can find it here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material3